# iOS4 SDK and iPad and @2x images

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, ipod

If I provide an image in both the standard size and now a new one with @2x for iPhone 4, which one with the iPad use?  If the user chooses the 2X feature to run the iPhone app in full screen on the iPad, do they seem the lower quality images stretched or will they see the higher quality images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lower quality images, at least in OS 3.2, which is pre-iPhone 4.

When iPad is updated to 4.x this might change.

Comment: We have that contracted out and we aren't iphone developers... I didn't realize that the iPad wasn't on version 4.0 yet.  Thanks!